# Crash: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

My application crashes due to **com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority**.

My Images are higher resolution images and I am resizing this images.

Is there any way to reduce the resolution of images?

Thanks.